# Can nikkah be pronounced via Skype?

Tags: nikah, internet

Is it possible for someone to have nikkah via skype?

Like having an Imam on either sides. That way will the nikkah be considered valid?

As some people don't believe in engagement because of bad eye (jinx/nazar).

Comment: yes it is possible you should say true nikah word or read it correctly

Answer (score 8):

Since Skype can be categorized as a form of telephone therefore, yes, nikah can be pronounced over Skype.

> **Question**: Is it valid to pronounce the marriage formula through a telephone?
>
> **Answer**: It is valid.

Source: Website of Ayatullah Sayyid Ali Husaini Sistani, [Marriage » Questions and Answers](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/46/2063/)

Answer (score 4):

People from different cultures do the Nikah in different ways e.g. in some tradition the bride is in one room and the groom in another. 
However I believe that the correct way is to have the bride and groom in the same room and facing each other. 
Now you are asking about Skype. I don't think it is permissible to have a 'Skype Nikah' because fraud can take place. There will be problems identifying the bride and groom. By this way you are not marrying somebody that who true identity you are unaware of. Also what if this is a trick to get something e.g. money or visa. Another reason is that the Imam performing the Nikah should feel comfortable and the witnesses too.
I would recommend waiting a bit longer and doing the Nikah face to face because I sure you don't want to continue the marriage as an only online relationship.

Comment: Welcome to Islam Stack Exchange. In this site it is a requirement to supply answers with supporting authenticate resources.

Comment: *"I don't think"* is definitely not an answer. The question is asking whether it's possible, or not. Therefore ideal conditions should be considered. It's not a requirement @Ghasan, please go through http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/378/3487.

Comment: -1, Scholarly reference is required

Answer (score 2):

Let me clarify the meanings of the Nikkah, actually Nikkah is an agreement between the to-be husband and to-be wife. In which the man agree to the statement, in which it is clearly told that:

> man's_name s/o father's_name, as per haq_mehr, accepts girl's_name d/o father's_name as his bride.

Then the same is repeated for the girl, to make her choice to be his wife or to reject this proposal.

Do you find something anywhere, where it is stated that the girl and boy should be in room facing each other? I don't find that.

Skype is a mean or a medium using which two people can communicate with each other. Skype is a good software but where there is good there is evil too. What Aisha was trying to say, was a great idea, and somewhat I do agree to her and I am of the point of view that Nikkah should be done inside a room (well not a room obviously, but the girl and the boy should be with each other).

If the girl and the boy are agreeing to Marry on Skype, they can, because no one is dumb enough to fall for a one day relation Nikkah in today's world. Sorry, but girls and boys in today's world come to know each other very well before even falling in love. So if they're going for a **love marriage** they already know each other. If they are going for an **arrange**, then no wonder its a good idea to marry on Skype, since there are many couples living in different countries, so spending some time on Skype would be better rather than spending money and wasting time waiting for Visa. Just do it! ;)