# Is marriage without the woman or her family present allowed by Islamic sharia?

Tags: sharia, nikah

Is it possible for a man and woman to marry when both of them are far and not in the presence of their family? The man will arrange the papers for marriage, without the presence of the woman or her family.

I need to know if it is allowed by the Islamic Sharia?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can nikkah be pronounced via Skype?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/can-nikkah-be-pronounced-via-skype) and [Marriage without Wali](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16398/marriage-is-done-without-wali)

Answer (score -2):

It would be okay if the girl and her father are satisfied with this marriage. Actually you can do it even though you are in two far places. For instance, you can say/recite its Siqah (its Islamic related sentence(s)...) by phone or other similar devices and she ought to declare that she agree as well. (By reciting its Siqah...)

For further information, refer to the site below as the source of it.

**Source:**

[portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir/node/2679/?ref=sbttl#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: Do you have a source that references ahadith?

Comment: To be honest, I couldn’t find the precise issue which you inquired. But as some relatively related matters which could be beneficial for you: 

http://www.al-islam.org/library/quran-hadith

 http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa2185 (En) / http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa2185 (Arabic) / .  (I hope the mentioned sites are constructive and profitable for you to some extent, otherwise I do apologize if couldn’t find the precise matter…/ Good luck mate.

Comment: JazakAllah alkhairen. I am always warey to follow advice that isn't backed up directly by Hadith or Quran, unless the advice comes indirectly via a shiekh or other learned muslim.